# MongoDB .populate

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm currently learning MongoDB why do we use `.populate()`. What is the difference between `.populate()` and `.virtual()`?

Can anyone tell me how they differ and when one should be used over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both serves a different purpose and one cannot be a replacement of other.

**Virtual:** If you want attributes that you can get and set but that are not themselves persisted to mongodb, virtual attributes is the Mongoose feature for you.Remember, only non-virtual properties work as part of queries and for field selection.[See Virtual](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/virtuals.html)

**Populate:** ObjectIds can refer to another document in a collection within our database and be populate()d when querying.It gives you [DBRef](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/#dbref-explanation)-like behavior. [See Populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/populate.html)